# Getting 'System.TypeInitializationException' when running project in Docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, csom

I have an assignment where I have to put my CSOM .NET CORE 2.2 project inside the docker.

The project consists of a console application that calls CSOM project (dll) that updates taxonomy fields.

When I run the project on its own it works fine.

When I put the project inside the Docker container and try to run it I get the following

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry' threw an exception.) ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry' threw an exception. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Registry is not supported on this platform.

Here is my Docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk

WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . ./
#RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/WebJobCore.dll"]
```

Here is the part of the code in the console app

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Testing webjob");

        Program t = new Program();
        t.RunSynchronizer().Wait();
    }

    public async Task RunSynchronizer()
    {
        var traceWriter = new ConsoleTraceWriter();
        var taxonomyFactory = new ItaTaxonomyFactory();
        var synchronizer = new ItaTaxonomySynchronizer(traceWriter, taxonomyFactory);

        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        await synchronizer.SyncAll();

        stopWatch.Stop();

        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("My RunTime " + elapsedTime);
    }
```

Here is the code from the external synchronizer dll

```
    public async Task SyncAll()
    {
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(ConfigSettings.SiteUrl))
        {

            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(
                "username",
                "password");
            var taxonomyService = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(context);
            var termStore = taxonomyService.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
            context.Load(taxonomyService);
            context.Load(termStore);
            await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
            }
         }
```

Here is my docker build command

```
docker build -t mylatestimage .
```

Here is my docker run command

```
docker run mylatestimage
```

When I run the executable of a console app or the project itself within the Visual Studio, everything runs fine. When I try to run the docker, I ONLY get the 'testing webjob' output and the program breaks at the 
await synchronizer.SyncAll() line producing the aforementioned error

Please let me know how I could fix it

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: _"Registry is not supported on this platform"_ - doesn't sound very promising.

Comment: Does it mean the docker will not work at all or should I take the code from the external dll into a single project?

Comment: It means you should work out which part of your code is trying to use the Windows registry, and see whether you can remove that. Note that I'd be surprised if this had anything to do with Docker itself - I suspect you'll get the same result just running on Linux without any containers involved.

Comment: But my project explicitly not using any registries at all

Comment: Does it mean that there is a call for registries somewhere inside of CSOM? Does it mean CSOM cannot be run on Linux at all?

Comment: the problem is rather with [AuthenticationManager](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Requests/tests/AuthenticationManagerTest.cs)

Comment: Selvin, is there a way to go around it? Or it is plain impossible to run csom in docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible after I switched to Windows containers on the Docker and pulled down Nano Server using this command

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver
```